# Error contacting API: status(statuscode = error, resolution=null)

Tags: java, android

I am newbie, I need help. Why do I get this error? Error contacting API: status(statuscode = error, resolution=null).

I already enable Google Places API. My keys are all good. I also use in the manifest geo.API_KEY. My permission is maybe complete. My gradles are also latest. Could you guys help me about this? Where did I get wrong?

**Map Activity**

```
package com.example.roadwarn;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private Boolean LocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE = 1234;
    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 18f;
    ImageView button_back, mGPS;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mFromText;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71, 136));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        button_back = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
        mFromText = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.input_from);
        mGPS = findViewById(R.id.my_gps_location);

        getLocationPermission();

        button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    //Key Events
    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: Initializing");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();

        mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);

        mFromText.setAdapter(mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter);

        mFromText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                        geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();

        mGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: GPS Location");
                getDeviceLocation();
                hideSoftKeyboard();
            }
        });
    }

    //Search Bar
    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: Geo Locating");
        String searchString = mFromText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: Geo Locating" + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: Found a Location" + address.toString());

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM, address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    //Current Location
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: Getting current location");
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {

            if (LocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task location = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Location is found");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM, "My Location");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Location is not found");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Unable to locate current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title) {
        Log.d(TAG, "zoomMap: Moving camera to: Latitude:" + latLng.latitude + "Longitude:" + latLng.longitude);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        if (!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title);
            gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    //Map
    private void initMap() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: Initializing map");
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady:Map is ready");
        gMap = googleMap;

        if (LocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    //Permission
    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: Getting location permission");
        String[] permissions = {FINE_LOCATION, COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                LocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: Called.");
        LocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: Permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    LocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: Permission granted!");
                    //initialize map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }


}
```

Comment: have you checked your logs? have you debugged your code? simply saying 'status is error' doesn't say anything